# Game Development - where to start to create powerful 3D applications

Tags: 3d

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeF1ZvA2IEQ

I'm interested in how to do the same? Ready to start from scratch with the basics. Only properly direct. 
Thank you.

(There is not a tag for ***game development***, but if there was, It would have been selected for this post.)

Comment: Google the same question.  (I did not down vote, but would guess ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*** is reason someone did)

Comment: thank you, I would like to ask advice from programmers. I dream of doing such a thing, I just need to know what it takes

Comment: See ideas below.  I am not a game developer, but can see the appeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, so there are a million directions we could go (which is the reason someone down voted your question earlier)  But, here are some ideas:

***First*** pick a language.  ***[I like C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html)***, but c++, Java,... (and many more) are all good.  (the list is large and distinguished). If one is available, a classroom course would be a good idea for what ever language you choose, but not absolutely necessary.
***Next***, pick a development environment/compiler.  I like ***[Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html)*** and ***[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)***, but there are many others.
***Next*** pick a graphics tool.  ***[I like OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)*** because it is open source, and well documented.  but others include ***[Asymptote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_%28vector_graphics_language%29)***, ***[and a lot more](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fclasses.soe.ucsc.edu%2Fcmps203%2FFall04%2Ffinalreports%2FProjectPaper_JerryYee.pdf&ei=wwCiU_ySOpfaoAST0IF4&usg=AFQjCNGHA1WhQaTvuPoCpTPB5YpcI5sp5g&sig2=9dn1oiadP8RmGDNi9I8hQA&bvm=bv.69411363,d.cGU)***.

***Once you master*** (or become proficient with) some variation of a language, development environment, and fundamental graphics, you should venture out ***[into game specific tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/five-free-game-development-tools-make-your-own-games/)***.   Again, the list is long.  Look around on Google for more.

These suggestions are not intended to point you down a specific path, but hopefully will get you started with a first step. The links I suggested all offer technology that is open, free to use and with plenty of tutorials. *Good luck*, I hope the best for you.